# How to view graphs of tensorflow benchmarks

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Using [tensorflow benchmarks](https://github.com/tensorflow/benchmarks), I'm trying to view Inception3 graph.

I noticed the `--graph_file` flag, which generates a graph file, but when trying to view it on `tensorboard` (by specifying its base dir to `--logdir`) I get **No graph definition files were found.**

Is that the right way to view the benchmark graphs?

Thanks in advance.